# How to check IF query string exists in Apache

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I am trying to check if the query string is not present in the HTTP request then set some headers. I am following this : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

I have tried -

```
 <If "! %{QUERY_STRING} ">
        Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=120"
  </If>
```

or

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} -z">
        Header always set Cache-Control "max-age=120"
  </If>
```

Getting syntax error.
Can you pls tell how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <If "%{QUERY_STRING} -z">
> ```

Should be the other way round:

```
<If "-z %{QUERY_STRING}">
```

Or, you could test that it is equal to the empty string:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} == ''">
```

Note that this tests if the query string is "empty", it might still exist. In other words, there could be a lone `?` on the end of the URL. In this case, arguably there is a query string, but it is empty.

If you need to be more strict and test whether there is any query string, even "empty" then check against `THE_REQUEST` for a literal `?`. For example:

```
<If "%{THE_REQUEST} !~ '\?'">
    # There is no query string, since there is no "?"
</If>
```

(`!~` operator does not match the regex.)